# Correct way to display formatted JSON data from rest api with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda

I have some data from an api (Lambda/Node JS) coming into my React app. How can I display line breaks and maybe some html elements like `<ul><li></li></ul>` etc. I have tried `\n` for line breaks.

My code so far is as follows:

**NodeJS**

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    if (event.httpMethod === 'GET') {
        return getData(event);
    }
    console.log(getData);
};

const getData = event => {

    let data = {
        "home": [{
                "title": "Home",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", 
                "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "about": [{
                "title": "About",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", 
                "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
            }
        ],
         "work": [{
                "title": "Work",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", 
                "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
            }
        ],
         "work_one": [{
                "title": "Work nested",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", 
                "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
            }
        ]
    };

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
    };
};
```

**React component**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import '../main/main.css';


  class Main extends Component {
     _isMounted = false;

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        awsApiData: [],
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: ''
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this._isMounted = true;
      console.log('app mounted');
      this.setState({ loading: true});
      /*global fetch */
      fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data, loading: false }, () => console.log(data)))
        .catch(err => { 
         this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});
        });

    }

        componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    render() {
      const data = this.state.awsApiData;
      return (
        <div className="main-content container">
        {this.state.errorMessage &&
        <h3 className="error"> Error: { this.state.errorMessage } </h3> }
           {this.state.loading ? <div className="text-center">Loading...</div> : (data && data.home) &&
              <div><h2>{data.home[0].title}</h2><br /><p className="mb-5">{data.home[0].body}</p>
               <img className ="image" src={data.home[0].image} alt="alternative tag"></img> 
              </div>
          }    
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Main;
```

Any idea's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render HTML and style `{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }` to handle whitespaces

Here's a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-microservice-t5rbu

```
export default function App() {
  const text =
    "One \n Two \n Three <ul><li>first item</li><li>second item</li></ul>";
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
      style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this for  new line below code dynamically generate div after dive
{"\n"}
Check this.. Just check if the awsApiData is set in state or not. hope this will work.mainly you have to use "map" function
{

```
 render() {
    const data = this.state.awsApiData;
    return (
        <div className="main-content container">
            {this.state.errorMessage &&
            <h3 className="error"> Error: { this.state.errorMessage } </h3> }
            {this.state.loading ? <div className="text-center">Loading...</div> :
                { this.state.awsApiData.home.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                        <div><h2>{item.title}</h2><br /><p className="mb-5">{item.body}</p>
                            <img className ="image" src={data.home[0].image} alt="alternative tag"></img>
                        </div>
                        )
                })
                }
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I don't follow? I want to be able to show line breaks and html elements from api

Comment: use like this..<div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
      style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}
    />